# Is it possible to disable the Command+Tab switcher while in a specific application only?

Tags: keyboard, window-manager

I using an RDPish client (Teradici PCoIP) and I would like for Command+Tab to activate the remote desktop's window switcher instead of my local one when I am in that program. Is there a way to tell my Mac to turn off the window switcher shortcut just while the Teradici client is my focused window?

Sidenote: I am actually using [Witch](https://manytricks.com/witch/) as my switcher (which is awesome btw), and I am able to turn that off on an app-specific basis. But once I've done that, the native switcher activates.

Another sidenote: The remote desktop uses linux + mate and actually maps Command to Ctrl. So, I want a way to press Command+tab, bypass the system Command+tab, Teradici sends it to the linux desktop that maps it to Ctrl+tab, which then detects the local Ctrl+tab program switching shortcut. Also open to suggestions on how to map Command differently on linux.

Comment: assign a useless shortcut for that app to cmd+tab. User defined shortcuts take precedence over system ones.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to set a shortcut in the remote desktop client. Tried setting one in an app on the remote desktop, but that didn't seem to work...